# Question on Homotopy Lemma in Milnor's “Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint”

Tags: analysis

In Milnor's book in the proof of homotopy lemma on p. 22 it is stated that if $y$ is a critical value of a function $f$ (assumptions as in that book), then there is a neighborhood $V_y$ of $y$ consisting of regular values of $f$ for which $\#f^{-1}(y)=\#f^{-1}(y')$, $y'\in V_y$, where $\#A$ denotes the number of elements of a set $A$. [This obviously implies that $\#f^{-1}(y')=\#f^{-1}(y'')$, $y',y''\in V_y\backslash\{y\}$]

Is the statement correct in view of the following example?

Let $f:[0,2\pi]\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=\sin x$, and put $y=1$. If $y'>1$, $\#f^{-1}(y')=0$ and for $y'<1$, but sufficiently close to $1$, $\#f^{-1}(y')=2$.

(or is the example incorrect?)

Comment: Your domain is a manifold with boundary.  Is that allowed in his theorem?

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing some things here. The statement you wrote down is not correct and also not claimed to be true in the book.

By assumption in the lemma, $y$ is a regular value of $f$ and $g$. In the proof the situation is considered that this $y$ is not a regular value for the smooth homotopy $F$ between $f$ and $g$. The claim about the existence of the neighbourhood, however, is applied to $f$ and $g$ and not to $F$.

(In general you should not ask this kind of question here without providing the necessary context. Not everyone visiting this site has each book which might be cited at his fingertips nor do people tend to know the books by heart).

Comment: You are right. I overlooked this crucial assumption.